# bluetooth settings+android

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings

In My Application i Need to check whether the device is discoverable or not and bletooth is on or off I applied the code like this

```
bluetoothenable=Settings.Secure.getInt(myContext.getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.Secure.BLUETOOTH_ON);
```

It gives true value when in settings i have checked bluetooth on but for discoverable 
i add this code

```
bluetooth=Settings.System.getInt(myContext.getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERABILITY);
```

it gives me Settings not found exception not this any value i check through 
`android.provider.Settings.System` it gives this error If we can not read settings value through
`android.provider.Settings.System`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html). With this adapter you can get isEnabled() and getScanMode()

Comment: Is this really the only option to get information about the current bluetooth settings? I've tried `Settings.System.getInt( getContentResolver(), Settings.System.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERABILITY )` and `Settings.System.getInt( getContentResolver(), Settings.System.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERABILITY_TIMEOUT )` on several Samsung and HTC devices and all of them throw a _android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException_. Why do they actually provide that settings provider if it doesn't work at all? :/

Comment: It might be that it can be done your way... but I have never done it like that. I have only had the need when I allready had the BluetoothAdapter setup so... I can't give a better answer